# Excel formula position of minimum value

Tags: excel, formula

EDIT: Likely an easy question, basically I have three values, let's say 9, 4 and 7 in different cells (**not in a table)**, I want to find the minimum in an order then return its relative position, **for example: 9,4,7 would return 2 as 4 is the minimum and is positioned second.**

What is the correct excel formula to do so? Thanks .

Solution: Thanks all for your help, I didn't think excel could do if it wasn't continuous. I've ended up using a series of nested IF statements, an AND statement and < signs, to get the job done :)

Comment: Just a sort question, what is it good for?

Comment: I would suspect the following to work as an array formula: `MAX(IF(INDEX(myareas,,,{1,2,3})=MIN(myareas),{1,2,3},0))`; just replace or define `myareas` with your individual cells… Only thing is, it does not work :/ Perhaps someone can explain?

Comment: @mousio: i agree one would expect that to work but `INDEX` doesn't appear to support array arguments (though curiously your formula seems to work as expected when array entered in two cells!) A workaround is to use `CHOOSE({1,2,3},A1,B2,C3)`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply;

```
=ROUND(MIN(A1,B1,C1), 0)
```

Ah, after clarification;

I can't think of a way to do that with a formula, it can be done with VBA (Assumes all numeric cells + the highest index is returned in the result of a clash)

```
=OrdinalMin(A2,B2,C2)

//in a module
Public Function OrdinalMin(ParamArray cells() As Variant) As Long
Dim i As Long, min As Double
For i = 0 To UBound(cells)
    If cells(i) <= cells(min) Then min = i
Next
OrdinalMin = min + 1
End Function
```

Comment: I would like to give the positon of the minimum in an array of values, not to round off.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an array formula that should work. It assumes the values are in A1, C3, and B4.

`=MAX(IF(CHOOSE(TRANSPOSE({1,2,3}),$A$1,$C$3,$B$4)=MIN($A$1,$C$3,$B$4),TRANSPOSE({1,2,3}),0))`

Comment: Good one! But there is absolutely no need to use `TRANSPOSE(…)`, and even if there was, then you could just use `;` instead of `,` to transpose it yourself :] Your solution can even be combined with `INDEX(…)` if you want to use a named reference.

Comment: Right you are... not sure why I did that. Thanks for the fix

Answer (score 1):

min: `=MIN(A1,B2,C3)`

position: `=MATCH(2,1/FREQUENCY(min,(A1,B2,C3)))`

Comment: I tried this and it works! But I do not understand the mechanism that you use here, could you please explain or point to a resource? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Excel lookup functions want continuos range of data.

For a set of random cells, use something like:

```
Public Function Match2(ByVal What As Variant, ByVal Where As Range) As Long
  Dim a As Range
  Dim c As Range
  Dim g As Long

  For Each a In Where.Areas
    For Each c In a.Cells
      g = g + 1

      If c.Value = What Then
        Match2 = g
        Exit Function
      End If
    Next
  Next
End Function
```

Usage:

```
=Match2(MIN(B6,F9,I16),(B6,F9,I16))
```

Answer (score 0):

Array formula:

```
{=SUM((B$16:M$16)*(B23:M23=MIN(B23:M23)))}
```

where the range `B$16:M$16` has the indices (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, etc), and `B23:M23` has the values being considered.