# Vlookup and get the min value (date)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

TOP Table is Input, and bottom table is preview for required output.

For Each ID I need to find earliest datetime. I also need other information from other columns (please see image below).

My current solution is:
In Cell E2 `=A2`
   Cell E3 drag down `=IF(E2<>A3,IF(E1=A3,"",A3),"")`

In Cell F2 drag down `=IF(E2<>"",MIN(IF($A$2:$A$14=E2,$C$2:$C$14)),"")`  Ctrl+Shift+Enter

[image]

Comment: `I also need other information from other columns` - please be more specific. And according to screen.. are there many separate tables on the sheet?

Comment: Sorry, I meant. For each ID (A) I need to find earliest Date in column (C) I also need other information from B & D

Comment: Once again: on your sample we have 2 tables with ID 9. So minimal data from ALL tables of for every table is required?

Comment: Are the `ID` values always increasing with steps of 1, or is that just the case in your example?

Comment: @PeterL. Minimum date is required for all ID's.

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek No But they won't be increasing by 1, but the will be sorted. they can increase by 5 or 3 or 10 or anything. but it will still be sorted.

Comment: @Mowgli pal you still don't understand me: if we have 2 tables (like on your screen), we either need to find minimal date for every ID among values of each table, or among ALL tables, i.e. I have ID 9 in every table, but for the last option I'll have only ONE minimal? Please clarify this, or better provide screen with E and F filled as desired (manually, for the example).

Comment: @PeterL. Sorry for confusion, Table1 on top is input(date), table 2 is required output. Thanks

Comment: @Mowgli now it's clear) However, that new table should be placed BELOW original or on the right? Are empty rows for not needed values OK?

Comment: @PeterL. on the right is fine. :) empty rows not needed.

Comment: that's ok for now) If you could share your sample which is screened - that would speed up the solution.

Comment: @PeterL. Here is link to DB file http://db.tt/PS25R0XE

Comment: I'm almost done. Are ID2 unique or may be the same in the table?

Comment: @PeterL. Same as the datetime stamp?

Comment: @Mowgli please see the answer - I think I found solution where uniqueness does not matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One more option without any intermediate calculations:

1. Select **the whole range starting** `E2` and to the last row where IDs are located - for the sample given it's row 14, so select range `E2:E14`: `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$14,SMALL(IF(MATCH($A$2:$A$14,$A$2:$A$14,0)=ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($A$2:$A$14))),MATCH($A$2:$A$14,$A$2:$A$14,0),""),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($A$2:$A$14))))),"")` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of usual <kbd>ENTER</kbd> - this will define a **Multicell ARRAY** formula and will result in curly `{}` brackets around it (but do **NOT** type them manually!).
2. `F2` (ID2): `=IF(E2="","",SUMPRODUCT(--(E2=$A$2:$A$14),--(G2=$C$2:$C$14),$B$2:$B$14))` - normal formula.
3. `G2` (Min Date): `=IF(E2="","",MIN(IF(E2=$A$2:$A$14,$C$2:$C$14,2^100)))` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of usual <kbd>ENTER</kbd> - this will define an **ARRAY** formula and will result in curly `{}` brackets around it (but do **NOT** type them manually!).
4. `H2` (InCh): `=IF(E2="","",INDEX($D$2:$D$14,SUMPRODUCT(--(E2=$A$2:$A$14),--(F2=$B$2:$B$14),--(G2=$C$2:$C$14),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($D$2:$D$14))))))` - normal formula.

Remarks:

- To make the solution more compact and easy to read, define named range for `ID` column, and then reference other data columns using `OFFSET`.
- ID2 values may not be unique - as they are on the sample for IDs `1...3`.
- Resulting set for `Min Date` should be formatted the same way as source `Date` row.
- The key formula of the solution - is multicell monster which returns unique IDs without empty rows - as OP requested)

Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d2098updfh8djnf/MinDateIDs.xlsx

Comment: +1 for working sample and clean solution without intermediates

Comment: Seriously thank you very much for your hard work.... I am just starting to see your workbook..I have question. I am trying to edit formula in column `E` it is throwing me error that cannot change any part of array.

Comment: @Mowgli that's expected for **multicell** array formulas - as stated. to edit it, you should select the whole range this formula uses.

Comment: @Mowgli will be able to respond in about an hour from now, so review the solution and get back if required

Comment: @PeterL. Solution is awesome, I works like a charm, but I am not sure how to implement on my worksheet, whenever you have time you can reply :)

Comment: @Mowgli please be more specific about troubles you face

Comment: with in your worksheet, when I try to change range for cell E2 it gives `You cannot change part of an array.`

Comment: @Mowgli pal, I replied above how to change it - select the whole region where the formula is placed, for my sample it's `E2:E14`.

Comment: @Mowgli this should help: http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/ss/2011-03-23-excel-2010-multi-cell-array-formula-sbs-tutorial.htm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25391/discussion-between-mowgli-and-peter-l)

Comment: @DougGlancy thanks! Even more pleased such experienced users upvote me)

Comment: @PeterL. Hey Peter there is glitch, I hope you can please please help me fix this. in the spreadsheet you have attached. if you change cell A3 to 1 and change C3 same time as C2 which is `2/1/2013  12:33:42 PM`. formula will return sum of B2 and B3 it should just return `39396`. thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry I meant formula in `F2` will return B2+B3 instead of just `39396`

Comment: @Mowgli it was so much long ago...) Well, if I understood your comments correctly - you now may have 2 or more IDENTICAL records for date? That's a totally different task then: how you should choose between them, I mean data from other columns? `For Each ID I need to find earliest datetime. I also need other information from other columns (please see image below).` - that's from your initial post, and now it appears that there could be 2 "earliest" records.

Comment: That's right, but there is one other columns in this which are not same, but `ID`, `ID2`,`Date`,`InCh` columns can have same data. if they are all same can't we just pick any of the ID2 if ID is same and timestamp are also same?

Comment: I think my alternate solution would to remove duplicate records. lol I know it has been so long but I never noticed this glitch. :)

Comment: @Mowgli I think I'll be able to dig back into this not earlier than upcoming weekend... but the solution wont be easy, despite the fact things look so.

Comment: @PeterL. thanks No problem take your time.. just FYI I have another column which as different type of timestamp, it has timestamp of `ReportedOn` (column title), I am deleting the timestamp with earlier time, and keeping record with more recent time. I am sorry this is confusing.n I will upload example to help you understand problem better.

Comment: Here is link to example file https://www.dropbox.com/s/etr9m9vfxet2oke/MinDateIDs_E.xlsx

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a challenge... I think I have found an approach that works. For the sake of clarity, I used a few helper columns. Also, I did not use any named ranges but stuck with the column-row indications. You might want to change that.

It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of XLS with helper columns]

and zooming in to the relevant columns:

[image: Screenshot of the newly inserted columns]

Column `F` contains an array formula to filter out duplicates. An approach is explained [here](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/04/14/create-a-unique-alphabetically-sorted-list-extracted-from-a-column/). The formula I used in `F2` is

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$14, MATCH(MIN(IF(COUNTIF($F$1:F1,$A$2:$A$14)=0, 1, MAX((COUNTIF($A$2:$A$14, "<"&$A$2:$A$14)+1)*2))*(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$14, "<"&$A$2:$A$14)+1)), COUNTIF($A$2:$A$14, "<"&$A$2:$A$14)+1, 0))
```

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm as array formula. Drag this down or copy into column `F`. Then columns `G` and `H` contain the starting and ending indices of the duplicate `ID` values. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10879544/1380680) helped, please upvote it :-). The two formulas used are:

```
=MATCH(2,1/FREQUENCY($F2,$A$2:$A$14))
```

in `G2`, and

```
=FREQUENCY($A$2:$A$14,$F2)
```

in `H2`. Again, drag them down to get the full column filled. Next, column `I` is for clarification only -- and for sanity checking. It contains the desired minimum date from each sub-array. Column `J` substitutes that formula into a `MATCH` to find the actual index of the desired date.

```
=MIN(OFFSET($C$2:$C$14,$G2-1,0,1+$H2-$G2,1))
```

in `I2` and

```
=$G2-1+MATCH(2,1/FREQUENCY(MIN(OFFSET($C$2:$C$14,$G2-1,0,1+$H2-$G2,1)), OFFSET($C$2:$C$14,$G2-1,0,1+$H2-$G2,1))
```

in `J2`. Finally, columns `L`, `M` and `N` index into the original set of data via

```
=INDEX(B$2:B$14,$J2)
```

in `L2`, which you can drag horizontally and then vertically.

When you are done, you can hide the helper columns, or fold everything into big formulas. Good luck with that... There might be an easier way to achieve this, but I did not find it.

Comment: I uploaded it here: http://temp-share.com/show/Pf3Yq8tK2 . Or let me know a better place to put it.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking at your file now, can you please look at my file and see if I can do step 2 and just skip step 1. this file will make more sense what i am trying to do. http://temp-share.com/show/f3Ygubvdn

Comment: I will look at that later, but a quick remark: I think that the approach you want to take there only works if all timestamps in `C` are unique. Is that indeed the case?

Comment: Yes, I am hoping since I am looking by `hh:mm:ss PM/AM` .

Comment: I uploaded an answer to your second question to http://temp-share.com/show/KdPfTmj8h . Check out the formulas in cells `F18:F28`. Please let me know if this is what you were looking for. Basically, this is the same formula as the one used in cell `F2` in the original answer.

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek my +1 for nice `FREQUENCY` examples - these are still hard to understand for me)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value from column D in G then assuming that column C values are unique you could just use a VLOOKUP, i.e. in G2 copied down

`=VLOOKUP(F2,C$2:D$14,2,0)`

Answer (score 0):

Per your picture, they're all in the same sheet.  Just sort by `ID`, then `Date` (ascending).  As you work your way down the `ID` column, each time the `ID` changes, you know you've found the row with the minimum `Date` for that specific `ID`.  Create an extra column to signify where `ID` changes occur, and filter for those rows (hide the column if you so desire).

And... voila.

Answer (score 0):

Know this link is old, but there is a much shorter and easier way!
How about using a pivot table using the Minimum as field setting and then do a `=GETPIVOTDATA()` to get the information back!
Seems a lot simpler as these formulas!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just realized I've been overthinking this...Excel keeps the top item and removes all that follow when removing duplicates. 
So if you are going to create an extra working table anyway, why not just copy the range/columns you want to keep, then use the basic sort. 
Sort first by ID, then by the column you want as the second filter. Be sure the sorts are in the order you want (e.g. newest to oldest, oldest to newest, A to Z, Largest to smallest, etc). 
Once the data is sorted, remove duplicates based on ID. You are left with all of your columns of data, filtered by newest/oldest/largest/smallest per individual. 
This worked for my table with 30,000+ records, filtered down to 1500 unique individuals with most recent (plus associated amount), and with a second filter, the largest (plus associated date) for each person.

Comment: Might be better served as a comment