# Excel formula for position of minimum value using embedded calculations for arguments

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this data in Excel

```
A1 = 12
A2 = 10
A3 = 1
A4 = 6
```

I would like to return the position of the A1:A3 value that is the shortest distance from A4. Therefore you need to compare the ABS(A1-A4) to ABS(A2-A4) to ABS(A3-A4). The answer in this case is 2.

From [Excel formula position of minimum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029749/excel-formula-position-of-minimum-value)

the answer should be

```
=MATCH(2,1/FREQUENCY(MIN(ABS(A1-A4),ABS(A2-A4),ABS(A3-A4)),(ABS(A1-A4),ABS(A2-A4),ABS(A3-A4)))
```

That returns an error.

Another solution should be

```
=MATCH(MIN(ABS(A1-A4),ABS(A2-A4),ABS(A3-A4)),{ABS(A1-A4),ABS(A2-A4),ABS(A3-A4)},0)
```

That also returns an error. I know I can calculate the above in multiple steps(cells) or VBA but I need to have one formula that returns the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need the following simple *array formula*, enter it then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=MATCH(MIN(ABS(A1:A3-A4)), ABS(A1:A3-A4),0)
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Brilliant! What if A1:A3 are all over column A?  Like A1,A30,A500 with data in between that I do not want to pickup.

Comment: @dataowl that's a totally different story.